# 2018 North Carolina State Building Code: Plumbing Code

Tags: plumbing

Some time ago, I registered for a Free account at [ICCSafe.org](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/NCPC2018) to study the North Carolina Plumbing Code.

I am looking for recommendations of additional good self study material.